# Use native CSS min/max functions with LESS

Tags: css, less

I want to use [the min() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min()) with a stylesheet written in LESS. However, LESS has its own min and max functions that precompute values (making it impossible to mix-and-match units). How do I get it so the output CSS has the min/max functions as I wrote them?

Here is the style in the LESS file, which should also be the expected output.

```
canvas {
    background: white;
    width: min(95vh, 95vw);
    height: min(95vh, 95vw);
}
```

I am using lessc 3.13.1, which produces the following error:

```
ArgumentError: error evaluating function `min`: incompatible types in <snipped> on line 49, column 12:
48     background: white;
49     width: min(95vh, 95vw);
50     height: min(95vh, 95vw);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use LESS' string escaping capabilities to pass along a plain string to the CSS.

```
canvas {
    background: white;
    width: ~"min(95vh, 95vw)";  
    height: ~"min(95vh, 95vw)"; 
}
```

**See Also**: [Less doesn't support new math functions (e.g. min, max) #3463](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3463)

Comment: An unnecessary semicolon has been added to the `width` property. And unfortunately the snippet won't be able to work because it doesn't support LESS.

Comment: That did the trick! I remembered LESS having some sort of syntax like it, but I couldn't find anything about it in the docs. Thanks.